# Planning to build a customized left-handed, low-profile keyboard. Need help choosing components

Tags: keyboards

###### Background

I'm considering building a keyboard after the following specifications:

- left-handed (numpad on the left hand side of the keyboard)
- low profile
- Bluetooth connectivity
- backlight.

Regarding left-handed keyboards, there aren't a whole lot of options out there (separate numpad and keyboard excluded) to begin with. If I also want Bluetooth connectivity, and backlight there is seemingly not one keyboard out there that meets all criteria. However, I found one that almost fit the bill, the [Epomaker (Skyloong) GK96LS](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002191357082.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.173538datnamip&mp=1):
[image: Epomaker GK96LS]

However, it has a "normal" height key profile. Fortunately, this keyboard also comes as a DIY kit, the [Epomaker (Skyloong) GK96LXS](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004584644112.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.173538datnamip&mp=1). So, I am considering buying the kit, and purchase low-profile switches and keycaps separately, and assemble the keyboard myself.

---

###### Keyboard parts

Searching around AliExpress, I found low-profile keycaps and switches that I think would fit:

- Keycaps: [XVX Horizon Low Profile Double-Shot Keycap Set (117-Key)](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004701877497.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.173538datnamip&mp=1)
- Switches: [Gateron KS-27 Low Profile Switch](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004620638633.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.173538datnamip&mp=1)
- Missing symbols (see picture above): [Glowing Transparent Modifier & Function Keys Stickers for Keyboard (Keyoverlay.com)](https://keyoverlay.com/modifier-and-function-signs/glowing-transparent-modifier-and-function-keys-stickers-for-keyboard)

---

###### Problem and questions

While assembling a keyboard sound like a fun project, I have never done it before. I am, therefore, uncertain whether the switches and keycaps I've selected will be compatible with the GK96LXS. I am also uncertain whether the selected items will cover everything I need to assemble a functioning keyboard. Making a customized keyboard is by far a more expensive solution than simply buying a keyboard, so I want to make sure I get it right. (Especially, since I have to order the components from China.)

I therefore have the following questions:

1. Will the selected DIY kit, switches and keycaps work together?
2. Does anyone have experience with using the selected stickers on the keyboard? How is the quality?
3. Is there any other keyboards, or, alternatively, DIY kits, switches and keycaps that would meet my listed specifications?

Comment: Why must it be Bluetooth? There is also the wireless ROG Claymore II (though it is probably lacking non-real time macro definitions on the keyboard itself (like many other keyboards (Ducky excluded)), requiring to use the Armoury bloatware (Windows only) to time optimise the macros).

Comment: My sister is left handed and still uses a normal laptop keyboard

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for the tip. A numpad that can be attached to whichever side you prefer, is definitely a nice feature, and I'd buy it if it had Bluetooth. The reason I want Bluetooth is because there's no wires and dongles, which I feel like I've had enough of in my life. I don't really want more wires cluttering my workspace, and dongles are frustrating because they stick out of my laptop. They tend to get in the way when I need to bring it with me, and they are small enough to easily get lost if detached.

Comment: @Irsu85 I'll kindly ask you to stay on topic. I did not ask whether I can use a right hand keyboard. As a left handed person, using peripherals designed for right handed people is something of a given.

Comment: True, but isn't giving alternatives of something hard to find in the comments also on-topic? I would not write an answer since it is something different but as a comment?

Comment: @Irsu85 If you could provide a concrete suggestion, that might be helpful. However, pointing out that left-handed can use a "regular" keyboard (numpad on the right hand side) is like pointing out that the sky is blue or water is wet. The reality of being left-handed is that you have to learn to use your non-dominant hand to accomplish certain tasks, because most tools/equipment were designed for use with the right hand in mind, this goes for most keyboards and mice as well.

Comment: @Irsu85 Consequently, I've been using regular, right handed mouse and keyboard since I first got a computer in 1997, as there was no other options back then. At this point I'm so used to using a right-handed mouse, I would have a hard time adjusting to using the mouse with my left hand. However, I've often felt that the arrows, delete button and numpad is somewhat inconveniently located "on the wrong side", as I have to remove my hand from the mouse to access these keys. (I assume this might be an issue for right-handed people as well.)